# Understanding ends as equalizers

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

While reading Fosco Loregian's ["This is the (co)end, my only (co)friend"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503) I found the following remark:

[image]

The product on the left ranges over objects in the category, but I'm confused by the so-called "double product" on the right, which seems to range over morphisms. In programmer-speak, that seems like a "type error" to me! Could someone "unpack" that part of the formula with a bit more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not perfectly clear to me what you have a problem with. However, writing $\mathbf{C}_0$ and $\mathbf{C}_1$ for the collections of objects and morphisms of $\mathbf{C}$, and writing $\text{dom}, \text{cod} : \mathbf{C}_1 \to \mathbf{C}_0$ for the maps sending a morphism to its domain and codomain respectively. The right hand side would be $$\prod_{f \in \mathbf{C}_1} F(\text{dom}(f),\text{cod}(f)).$$
But this could be also written as
$$\prod_{(c,c')\in \mathbf{C}_1^2} \left( \prod_{f \in \hom(c,c')} F(c,c')\right).$$

Comment: About the product inside the parentheses of your second formulation: it is a product of F(c,c') with itself multiple times, one copy of F(c,c') for each morphism between c and c', is that correct?

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see that my article is being studied :)

Another way to visualize the situation is the following, which generalizes to the enriched context:

The end of $T\colon {\bf C}^\text{op}\times {\bf C}\to {\bf D}$, for ${\bf C},{\bf D}\in {\cal V}\text{-}{\bf Cat}$ is the limit of the diagram
$$
\prod_{c\in \bf C} T(c,c) \rightrightarrows \prod_{c,c'\in\bf C} T(c,c')^{{\bf C}(c,c')}
$$
where $X^V$ denotes the [power](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power) of an object of $\bf D$ with an object of $\cal V$.
Obviously, this characterization works only when these powers exist, but this is a rather mild condition. Coends in enriched setting are defined and used in [Gra80, §2.3] and [Dub70]: I warmly invite you to use these as references.

Thanks again for your patience in reading my paper!

Comment: Thanks. I have a small doubt remaining. How can one recover the morphisms of the end-as-dinatural-transformation (one for each element of the category C) from the single morphism of the equalizer? It it by composing the morphism of the equalizer with the various projections of the product?

Comment: Yes, the universal property of the end turns it canonically into a subobject of a big product $\prod_c T(c,c)$, so that you have the arrows $\int_c T(c,c) \to T(c',c')$ by composition $\int_c T(c,c) \to \prod_c T(c,c) \xrightarrow{p_{c'}}T(c',c')$

Comment: I have yet another doubt... I'm stuck trying to prove the commutativity of the dinatural transformation diagram, starting from the end-as-equalizer definition. How do I produce the $T(c,c) \to T(c,c')$ and $T(c',c') \to T(c,c')$ morphisms, with the required properties?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't understand your question: the arrows $T(c,c)\to T(c,c')$ and $T(c',c')\to T(c,c')$ are induced by functoriality of $T$.